# WPF: windowsformshost with webbrowser is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, performance

I need to suppress script errors, context menu and shortcuts in WebBrowser control in my application. But WPF WebBrower doesn't support this actions. So, I use WinForms WebBrowser. But WinForms WebBrowser is very slow during resizing of WindowsFormsHost control.

What do you recommend me?

P.S. I use .Net framework 3.5

Comment: It is completely unclear what "it control" might mean.

Comment: Fixed. Is description clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution: make resizing without animation.
Forexample:

```
<GridSplitter ShowsPreview="true" ... />
```